# Kafka topics not working after few days of creation

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am newbie to Kafka, few days back from producer few topics are created ( automatically) i.e. with partition 1 , reflection fact -1 and ISR -1.
 It worked fine , used to consume all topics messages fine.

Today i.e. after two days I ran my producer and consumer program and vice-versa too, but my consumer not able to consume/read message from the topic.
I checked all logs , no clue found what went wrong.

What is going wrong ?
Will the topics become stale after some time?
Is there any property value i need to check in kafka-server properties ?

Please help me.

Thank you.
~Shyam

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can check the health of kafka cluster with the various tools provided.

1. Use the ConsumerOffsetChecker class provided to validate if there is any lag between the producer and consumer.

   ```
   bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker --zkconnect <zk host/ip>:<zk port> --group <consumer group name>
   ```
2. Use the JMX metrics such as belowto verify if the messages are been produced at the cluster level and there are additional metrics.

   ```
   kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec
   kafka.network:type=RequestMetrics,name=RequestsPerSec,request={Produce|FetchConsumer|FetchFollower}
   ```
3. Use the Console Consumer to validate if the messages are present on the topic

   ```
   bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper <zk host/ip>:<zk port> --topic test --from-beginning
   ```
4. Verify the log.retention.XXX values in kafka configuration(server.properties file)

Additional JMX monitoring details and configurations are available in [documentation link](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#monitoring)

The last point is a little complicated to explain but I will try. Look at the [blog link on confluent.io](http://www.confluent.io/blog/how-to-choose-the-number-of-topicspartitions-in-a-kafka-cluster/),it talks about the producers buffering the message before sending them to broker in the section **More Partitions May Require More Memory In the Client**. Not sure if your problem is related.